# Equivalence RKHS Minimization

Tags: regression, nonlinear-regression, kernel-trick

Take a kernel $K$. You want to use this kernel in a regression context. I read that the kernel rigde regression solution with kernel $K$ is equivalent to redefine the kernel $K$ as $K_{eq}(x,x') = K(x, x') + \lambda \delta(x, x')$ where $\lambda  \geq 0$ and $\delta$ is the kronecker symbol.

What I don't understand is equivalent in what way? Because if you work in the RKHS associated with $K_{eq}$, I don't see how you can obtain the same regression solution as the kernel ridge regression with kernel $K$ and the regularization parameter $\lambda$. What am I missing?

To give more details, in several papers, I have seen people using:
$||f||_{H_K}^2 = Y^{T}(K(X,X)+\lambda I_N)^{-1}Y$ instead of $||f||_{H_K}^2 = Y^{T}(K(X,X))^{-1}Y$.